# Check Z-index of map polygon

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

lets say I have a situation where I have a few polygons ontop of eachother like this

[image]

is there a way to know what polygon is on-top aka the z-index of it? I didn't see anything in the docs but I was hoping I just missed it somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is - http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html#getZIndex()

StackOverflow wants 30 characters out of me, so here they are.